# mysqld directory disappears after using sudo service mysql stop

Tags: 16.04, mysql, sockets

Recently upgraded to 16.04 from 14.04. Apache2 works and PHP client works. But `/var/run/mysqld` goes missing after stopping or restarting MySQL service. Tried to uninstall MySQL 5.7 and reinstall, and the directory is restored with `mysqld.sock`. This continues to disappear after stopping/restarting MySQL.

When the directory disappears, it becomes impossible to load MySQL with login and password errors. Safe mode also does not work.

Turns out this is a bug with MySQL 5.6 on Ubuntu. It's not verified that it's also a bug on 5.7, but had the same problem as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.6/+bug/1435823. Found a different workaround before trying #3 on this page. Maybe #3 would have also worked.

Adding below as part of the problem, since this is what happens when this directory disappears:

```
# Unable to log in to MySQL 5.7 with or without passwords or in safe mode on Ubuntu 16.04 #
```

This was the original problem. I tried uninstalling MySQL 5.7 and re-installing. That did not work. When I had re-installed,  I used root as the user with no password. No combination of user/password worked, even if correct. After rebooting MySQL, I searched for the .sock file , which I could not find, hence the subject of this question. I'm using MySQL 5.7.17 for Linux (i686).

Comment: Did this workaround:
    `sudo service mysql stop`;
    `mkdir /var/run/mysqld/`;
   `chown mysqld /var/run/mysqld/`
After restarting MySQL, it worked normally. Would like to post this as an answer but so far my answers aren't popular enough.

Comment: Thanks @DavidFoerster. Got a message saying I posted too many answers without an upvote. Unfortunately, the questions I've answered aren't popular enough to get voted up. I ended up deleting an answer to see if I could post this answer, but that didn't work. Now I see why. Thanks. :]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't remember what the question was to undelete my answer and don't see a way to find it otherwise. I wish someone would upvote my question though! :)

Comment: Thanks David. I don't care enough to repost my answer. But I did get more reputation on StackOverflow for the same answer. :)

Comment: @DavidFoerster I guess time has removed my ban. I've reposted the answer. Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 1):

Did this workaround:

```
sudo service mysql stop
mkdir /var/run/mysqld/
chown mysqld /var/run/mysqld/
```

After restarting MySQL, it worked normally.

Comment: This does not seem to work in 18.04 :(